# Can I use Google maps tiles in OSM for Iran?  

Tags: google-maps, web-mapping, openstreetmap

I use Google maps in my application but because this service has limitation (2500 request per day for Geocoding) I want to use OSM instead of Google maps.

But OSM doesn't cover Iran as well as Google maps. My question is: Can I use Google maps tiles in OSM for Iran?

You can compare Google maps tiles with OSM in Iran on the following pictures: First is OSM and second is Google maps.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you cant. Google maps and OSM are 2 different WMS providers. On the side note, the api limit for Google maps is 25000 map loads per day i think, not 2500. Thats for geocoding service. Oh, and even the 25000 limit per day is a calculated average over 90 days!

Comment: thanks, But Geocoding service has 2500 limit per day!.I want to use map in my gps tracking application.If i use google map i don't know my application can respond to users request or no!.Please help me about this issue.

Comment: How can i use OSM in my application that has better cover like Google map.I want to have reverse geocoding over lat lon that send from gps device, so i don't know how can i solve limitation problem with google map api!

Comment: OSM cant have better cover, unless someone updated the data in that particular area. About geocoding using other services than google maps geocoder, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063093/how-do-i-do-geocoding-and-routing-with-openstreetmap

Answer (score 0):

Beside your technical problem, check out google maps API ToS
10.2 (c)
https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

You can't use API for car tracking.